# adding a list to itemsource, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am starting with WPF and I have this problem. I have a file called MainWindow.xaml with this code:

```
<Window x:Class="View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:View" xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="boardView">
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And I have another file called MainWindow.xaml.cs with this code

```
namespace ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var items = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
           
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have to assign this list to boardView.ItemsSource. How can I do that?

Comment: In broad brush strokes, you need a View Model class having a property you can bind your `ItemsControl` to. (i.e.  `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NameOfPropertyInYourViewModel}"`)  Read up on MVVM in WPF.   `MainWindow` is not a View Model, so I'm not sure why you have it in a namespace called `ViewModel`.

Comment: If you just want to do it the old-school way, you can try `boardView.ItemsSource = items;` in your `MainWindow` method.  You can find out more about how all this works by reading [here](https://wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/).

Comment: I think that the problem is that I can't use boardview in my MainWindow method. I don't know why, it's the name of ItemsControl. Do you know why?

Comment: your namespaces are not matching. Your XAML is in `View` but the partial class is in `ViewModel`

Comment: You should really learn how binding in WPF works. It's essential: [Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0). It's a short but informative and highly recommended read.

Comment: Move your code to `View.MainWindow.xaml.cs`.

Answer (score 1):

You have four problems here that I can see that would need to get fixed for this to work.

1. In order for data binding to work, you need to set the `DataContext` of your MainWindow.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    // Put this in the constructor after InitializeComponents();
    this.DataContext = this;
```

2. Another requirement for data binding is to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the class you wish to having data binding (in your case this is MainWindow, but I recommend you read on MVVM design):

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

3. Data bindings only work on public properties, so using `var items` isn't following this requirement. Instead, make `var items` a public property that updates itself with the PropertyChanged event whenever the value changes.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    private List<string> items;
    public List<string> Items 
    { 
       get => this.items; 
       set 
       { 
           this.items = value; 
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyName(nameof(Items))); 
       }
    }
```

4. Lastly, you need to fix your binding in the xaml to bind to your public property.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="boardView">
```

Comment: I like you are offering how to make it work within the MainWIndow itself instead of a full-fleged MVVM pattern.  Let the person understand the basics of a property and binding via get/set vs trying to engross themselves on a completely deeper level context while learning.  But you DID mention to read into MVVM which is obviously the next leg for them to go forward.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is not the preferred property change notification hook for controls or DependencyObject in general. In case of DependencyObject you should always implement properties as dependency properties. Because of performance reasons and especially because controls usually are the binding target.

Comment: In case of binding to a collection, you would also prefer using a ObservableCollection over a property that raises change notifications.